# How to extract jpg images from html files?

Tags: command-line, 20.04, html

I have a number of html files, all containing an embedded image.  I know it is possible to open each html file individually in a web browser and save the image from there.  The quantity I have would make this laborious.

Is it possible to do this in batch form?  What I mean is, is there a command I can use in Terminal to extract all images from the html files?

Looking online, I see various methods of doing this from pdf files but cannot find anything relating to html files.

Any and all help appreciated.  Thank you.

Comment: Does this help? https://helpcenter.octoparse.com/hc/en-us/articles/360018324071-How-to-download-images-from-a-list-of-URLs-

Comment: Where did you saved all your files. Mention the location. If all your files are located under one folder means it will be easy to extract images.

Comment: Sasuke Uchiha:  No, I was not aware of that link. I will look into it.  Thank you.

Comment: A Umar Mukthar:  Thank you.  Yes, all my html files are in one diretory called html.